# Why isn't the dynamically allocated memory for an array declaration and a pointer to an array declaration the same in C?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following C code snippet:

```
int main() {
  int *crr;
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 45};
  crr = (int *)malloc(sizeof arr);
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof arr);
  printf("%ld", sizeof crr);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is :

```
16
8
```

I have 64 bit architecture system. Hence, int is 4 bytes. Need explanation or any references for why this is happening. I've allocated same amount of memory to the `crr`.

Comment: `sizeof array` != `sizeof pointer`. You may like section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @pmg so will i be safe to do `crr[3] = 4`

Comment: Yes, in this case. Because `sizeof arr` is large enough (it's <number of elements> * <sizeof each element> == <4 * 4>). `crr` **points to** a memory block with 16 bytes, enough space for 4 integers; `arr` **is a** memory block with enough space for 4 integers.

Comment: Hence sizeof crr gives me size of the pointer?

Comment: Correct! `crr` is a pointer; `sizeof crr` gives the size of the pointer.

Comment: @pmg Thank you for the quick response and efforts.

Comment: `crr[3] = 4` is only correct after you verified that `crr != NULL`

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof arr` evaluates to the size of `arr` in bytes. Because `arr` is an array of four  four-byte `int`, its size is 16 bytes.

`sizeof crr` evaluates to the size of `crr`. Because `crr` is an eight-byte pointer, its size is eight bytes.

You may be accustomed to the fact that arrays are often automatically converted to pointers. When an array is passed to a function, it is converted to a pointer. When an array is used in an index expression, such as `arr[2]`, it is converted to a pointer (and then the index is added to it with pointer arithmetic, and the resulting pointer is dereferenced, as if it had been written `*(arr+2)`). This automatic conversion does not occur with `sizeof`. C 2018 6.3.2.1 3 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of *type*” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to *type*” that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue…